# Audio Not Working on Samsung Monitor via Thunderbolt

Tags: display, audio, thunderbolt

I have a 2022 13' MBA connected to a Samsung TU872 32-inch 4k Viewfinity monitor via Thunderbolt. It displays the screen just fine, but the audio doesn't work. The speakers do show up in settings and Audio MIDI, but the volume bar is greyed out when I select it and there is no sound output. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!